# Sentence Similarity for Text Classification

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, embedding, huggingface

I'm trying to use sagemaker with sentence similarity for text classification. There are three different classes: Reportable, Not Reportable, and Review.

Looking at the similarity scores, the values almost have no difference. Like this example:

```
[{'id': 'G CELL TUMOR has been determined to be Suspected', 'text': 'REPORTABLE', 'score': 0.8180783987045288}, {'id': 'G CELL TUMOR has been determined to be Typical', 'text': 'REPORTABLE', 'score': 0.8180783987045288}, {'id': 'Favors is the diagnosis of FULMINANT', 'text': 'REPORTABLE', 'score': 0.8180783987045288}, {'id': 'Favored is the diagnosis of FULMINANT', 'text': 'REPORTABLE', 'score': 0.8180783987045288}, {'id': 'Typical is the diagnosis of G CELL TUMOR', 'text': 'REPORTABLE', 'score': 0.8180783987045288}, {'id': 'Tumor is the diagnosis of G CELL TUMOR', 'text': 'REPORTABLE', 'score': 0.8180783987045288}, {'id': 'FULMINANT has been determined to be Malignant appearing', 'text': 'REPORTABLE', 'score': 0.8180783987045288}, {'id': 'FRANKLINS has been determined to be Suspicious', 'text': 'REPORTABLE', 'score': 0.8180783987045288}, {'id': 'Suspect is the diagnosis of FRANKLINS', 'text': 'REPORTABLE', 'score': 0.8180783987045288}, {'id': 'FULMINANT has been determined to be evolving', 'text': 'REPORTABLE', 'score': 0.8180783987045288}]
```

How can I increase the difference between the scores to get more variability with them?